# Android my own listener

Tags: java, android, listener, event-listener

I have an ActionBar and it has Tabs.
In the MainActivity there is a String variable.
In one Tab there is a TextView and a method setTv(String string) what can change the text in it.

I would like to make a Listener interface what can call the setTv(String string) method, when the str String is changes in the MainActivity.

Could anybody help me and fill in this code with the implementation?

This is the MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, LocationListener{

    ActionBar actionbar;
    ViewPager viewpager;
    FragmentPageAdapter ft;
    String str;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        ft = new FragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        actionbar = getActionBar();
        viewpager.setAdapter(ft);
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Run").setTabListener(this));
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Map").setTabListener(this));
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Statistics").setTabListener(this));
        viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {            

        });

}
```

This is the Fragment code:

```
public class RunFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView tv;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.run_layout, container, false);
        tv =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        return view;

    }


    public void setTv(String string){
        tv.setText(string);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have methods but I didn't copy these there

Answer (score 0):

Get your current fragment in your viewpager:

```
RunFragment fragment = (RunFragment) ft.getItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

Call your method where you want(after change str):

```
fragment.setTv("string");
```

Comment: From where get I get the fragmentID?

Comment: Apology I noticed you're using viewpager

Comment: The idea is the same get your current fragment of your viewpager and call your method.

Comment: And how can i get my fragment? Sorry I'm a beginner I have started programming android just a few days ago. Can you write the full code?

Comment: What class is your viewpager adapter extending?

Comment: public class FragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

 public FragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
  super(fm);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

Comment: public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  switch (arg0) {
  case 0:
      return new RunFragment();
  case 1:
      return new MapFragment();
  case 2:
     return new StatisticsFragment();
  default:
   break;
  }
  return null;
 }

 
 public int getCount() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return 3;
 }

}

Answer (score 0):

For the best way i recommend to you make a class that extends [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

from the docs :

> Base class for those who need to maintain global application state

So you can store your `str`  variable in this class and notify any launched Activities of variable state change. Actually i recommend to use [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

### MyApplication :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication singleton;
    private String str;
    private ArrayList<StringObserver> observerList = new ArrayList<StringObserver>();
    public MyApplication getInstance(){
        return singleton;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        singleton = this;
    }

    public void setString(String str) {
        this.str = str;
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public void addObserver(StringObserver obs) {
        observerList.add(obs);
    }

    public void removeObserver(StringObserver obs) {
        observerList.remove(obs);
    }

    private void notifyObservers() {
        for(StringObserver obs : observableList) {
            obs.notifyAboutStringChanged(str);
        }
    }
}
```

### StringObserver :

```
public interface StringObserver {
    void notifyAboutStringChanged(String str);
}
```

### And usage :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity/*or Activity*/ implements StringObserver {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        MyApplication appState = ((MyApplication )this.getApplication());
        appState.addObserver(this);
        appState.setString("This string was changed");
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyAboutStringChanged(String str) {
     // do something
    }

}
```

### In other Activity/Fragment :

```
public class RunFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView tv;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.run_layout, container, false);
        tv =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        return view;

    }


    public void setTv(String string){
        tv.setText(string);
        (MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication().setString(string); // this string notify your activity about value change.
    }

}
```